# filter range date elasticsearch

Tags: date, filter, elasticsearch, range

This is how my datas look like

```json
{
  "name": "thename",
  "openingTimes": {
    "monday": [
      {
        "start": "10:00",
        "end": "14:00"
      },
      {
        "start": "19:00",
        "end": "02:30"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to query this document saying, `opened on monday between 13:00 and 14:00`.
I tried this filter but it doesn't return my document:

```json
{
  "filter": {
    "range": {
      "openingTimes.monday.start": {
        "lte": "13:00"
      },
      "openingTimes.monday.end": {
        "gte": "14:00"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I simply say `opened on monday at 13:00`, it works:

```json
{
  "filter": {
    "range": {
      "openingTimes.monday.start": {
        "lte": "13:00"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or even `closing on monday from 14:00`, works too:

```json
{
  "filter": {
    "range": {
      "openingTimes.monday.start": {
        "gte": "14:00"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but combining both of them doens't give me anything. How can I manage to create a filter meaning  `opened on monday between 13:00 and 14:00` ?

## EDIT

This is how I mapped the `openingTime` field

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "monday": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "start": {"type": "date","format": "hour_minute"},
        "end": {"type": "date","format": "hour_minute"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## SOLUTION (@DanTuffery)

Based on @DanTuffery answer I changed my filter to his (which is working perfectly) and added the type definition of my `openingTime` attribute.

For the record I am using elasticsearch as my primary db through Ruby-on-Rails using the following gems:

```ruby
gem 'elasticsearch-rails', git: 'git://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails.git'
gem 'elasticsearch-model', git: 'git://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails.git'
gem 'elasticsearch-persistence', git: 'git://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails.git', require: 'elasticsearch/persistence/model'
```

Here is how my openingTime attribute's mapping looks like:

```ruby
attribute :openingTimes, Hash,    mapping: {
                                    type: :object,
                                    properties: {
                                      monday:     {
                                        type: :nested,
                                        properties: {
                                          start:{type: :date, format: 'hour_minute'},
                                          end:  {type: :date, format: 'hour_minute'}
                                        }
                                      },
                                      tuesday:     {
                                        type: :nested,
                                        properties: {
                                          start:{type: :date, format: 'hour_minute'},
                                          end:  {type: :date, format: 'hour_minute'}
                                        }
                                      },
                                      ...
                                      ...
                                    }
                                  }
```

And here is how I implemented his filter:

```ruby
def self.openedBetween startTime, endTime, day
  self.search filter: {
                nested: {
                  path: "openingTimes.#{day}",
                  filter: {
                    bool: {
                      must: [
                        {range: {"openingTimes.#{day}.start"=> {lte: startTime}}},
                        {range: {"openingTimes.#{day}.end"  => {gte: endTime}}}
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First create your mapping with the `openingTimes` object at the top level.

```
/PUT http://localhost:9200/demo/test/_mapping
{
  "test": {
    "properties": {
      "openingTimes": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "monday": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "start": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "hour_minute"
              },
              "end": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "hour_minute"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Index your document

```
/POST http://localhost:9200/demo/test/1
{
  "name": "thename",
  "openingTimes": {
    "monday": [
      {
        "start": "10:00",
        "end": "14:00"
      },
      {
        "start": "19:00",
        "end": "02:30"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

With a nested filter query you can search for the document with the `start` and `end` fields within boolean range queries:

```
/POST http://localhost:9200/demo/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "openingTimes.monday",
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "range": {
                    "openingTimes.monday.start": {
                      "lte": "13:00"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "range": {
                    "openingTimes.monday.end": {
                      "gte": "14:00"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your filter works perfectly, I would never have found it by myself. I added the changes I made to my code based on your answer in an edit.